# Allowing ClickOnce applications to be Installed over the Internet

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application that I want to offer for download on my website on the Internet.

I've run into an issue though since links to ClickOnce installation files can only be run from [Internet Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) though ([Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) and [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) can do it, but only with plug-ins pre-installed). The user may be using Chrome at the time and most likely won't have the extension installed.

My idea to overcome this is, rather than point to the ClickOnce application link for the install, I instead let the user download a setup.exe file (written with [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)). This setup.exe file does nothing but launch a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) through Internet Explorer by using System.Process to launch iexplore.exe and pass it the URL of the ClickOnce application as a command line parameter.

I think this should work fine and overcome my issues. Do you see issues with this approach or would you recommend a different approach for handling this?

Comment: I personally have a real pet peeve with applications launching Internet Explorer _directly_. I'd prefer to have a typical setup installer than a hack like that. I don't know if that's feasible or not for you, but here's a quick link I found through google that might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/2ad1f3c7-a8e4-49b3-a3bf-84b9dee90ed8

Comment: Why don't you let them download the setup.exe that is generated with the ClickOnce deployment? After all, the html file that is also generated has a link the purpose of which is exactly that.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair By passing a url that points directly to the installation file, Internet Explorer doesn't actually open up.  Just uses the system process to launch the installer.  Seamless to the end user.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @FanerYedermann Agghh!  I'm an idiot.  I've worked with the .application files for so long that I forgot a setup.exe gets generated as well.  I've never tested it, but I assume it can be distributed and installed remotely.  Thanks.